# include _SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . _SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ] fails to find the currently running script

Tags: php, file, include

I'm attempting to include files using the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable. So far, every file I've tried to include has thrown an file-not-found error. I assumed that I was just getting the directory wrong, so then I tried to include the currently running script. I'd expect it to recursively include itself until it ran out of stack and fell over.

```
echo( 'document root = ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '<br>' );
echo( 'script name   = ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '<br>' );

$szServerPath   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$szIncludePath  = $szServerPath . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
echo( "including     = " . $szIncludePath );
include( $szIncludePath );
```

This results in the following output:

```
document root = /var/httpd/htdocs
script name = /CSRC/Damflask/Main/Articles/index.php
including = /var/httpd/htdocs/CSRC/Damflask/Main/Articles/index.php
Warning: include_once(/var/httpd/htdocs/CSRC/Damflask/Main/Articles/index.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/glmorriL/CSRC/Damflask/Main/Articles/index.php on line 33
```

It looks like it still can't find the file. Every other file I've included presented the same error message. Why wouldn't this work?

EDIT: It seems the difference is due to an "alias". 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php (See Jamie's comment from 2 years ago).
Is there no equivalent path? It looks like DOCUMENT_ROOT is completely useless to me.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2):

You can see from the error message that your file path should be:

```
/home/www/glmorriL/CSRC/Damflask/Main/Articles/index.php
```

So obviously `/var/httpd/htdocs/...` won't find it.

Try using the `__FILE__` magic constant instead.

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific? I've not used `__FILE__`. `__FILE__` will give me "/home/www/glmorriL"?

Comment: Printing out `__FILE__` in that document gives me:
/home/www/glmorriL/CSRC/Damflask/Main/Articles/index.php
The point of using DOCUMENT_ROOT is that it gives me the root. I'm currently including documents with relative paths. I'd like to use the root path instead. Unfortunately this won't help me because it gives me the full path of the current file.

Comment: Apparently `__DIR__` doesn't exist, but I would have expected it to give me the directory that the current script is running in (and not the root).